# Excel Power Query performance optimization

Tags: excel, query-optimization, powerquery

I want to enrich my Excel table with live currency exchange data without dependency on Microsoft 365 subscription (co-called "Stocks" functionality).

To do that, I wrote the following Power Query:

```js
let EXCHANGE_DATA = Table.FromRecords({[

        EUR2ILS = try Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/eur-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0}[#"Exchange rate(1 EUR → ILS)"]
                    otherwise Text.Replace(Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/eur-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0}[Israeli New Sheqel], " ILS", ""),

        USD2ILS = try Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/usd-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0}[#"Exchange rate(1 USD → ILS)"]
                    otherwise Text.Replace(Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/usd-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0}[Israeli New Sheqel], " ILS", "")
    ]})
in EXCHANGE_DATA
```

Then I decided to make it clearer and extracted the data retrieval to the separate variables:

```js
let EUR2ILS = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/eur-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0},
    USD2ILS = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/usd-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0},

    EXCHANGE_DATA = Table.FromRecords({[

        EUR2ILS = try EUR2ILS[#"Exchange rate(1 EUR → ILS)"]
                    otherwise Text.Replace(EUR2ILS[Israeli New Sheqel], " ILS", ""),

        USD2ILS = try USD2ILS[#"Exchange rate(1 USD → ILS)"]
                    otherwise Text.Replace(USD2ILS[Israeli New Sheqel], " ILS", "")
    ]})
in EXCHANGE_DATA
```

This approach adds additional "Navigation" step into Applied steps queue.

From performance point of view, which approach should I prefer in Power Query?

1. Retrieving the data directly, specifying the final column:

```js
let EXCHANGE_DATA = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/eur-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0}[Israeli New Sheqel]
```

2. Or I can firstly retrieve the whole data and only then to specify a particular column:

```js
let EUR2ILS = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://transferwise.com/gb/currency-converter/eur-to-ils-rate")){0}[Data]{0}

EXCHANGE_DATA = EUR2ILS[Israeli New Sheqel]
```